# List sorting based on another List's order Issue

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, comparator

I have a `list` of `Strings` named `cardNameAndDescription` in a class called `GlobalDataHolder`and i am sorting these `Strings` alphabetically with the `Collections.sort();` method. However, each String in this `list` is associated with an `image` in another `list` called `mGLBIcons` which is located inside an `Adapter class'` called `UserBoxGlbImageAdapter`. When the `List<String>` gets sorted, I need to sort the `List<Integer>` (images) so that the `image` to `String` association doesn't get messed up.However, when I try and swap the `images` based on the custom `Comparator's` results, the `images` do not at all match with the `Strings`.Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?I think I might have misunderstood how the *Comparator class sorts collection*s. Here's my code:

```
            GlobalDataHolder.cardNameAndDescription.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                int s1Pos = GlobalDataHolder.cardNameAndDescription.indexOf(s1);
                int s2Pos = GlobalDataHolder.cardNameAndDescription.indexOf(s2);
                if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)) {
                    return 0;
                } else if(s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) > 0)  { //greater than s2
                    Log.v("card_names","1");
                    Collections.swap(UserBoxGlbImageAdapter.mGLBIcons,s1Pos,s2Pos);
//                        UserBoxGlbImageAdapter.refreshFragmentView(UserBoxGLBFragment.getUserBoxAdapter());
                        return 1;
                    } else if(s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) < 0) { // less than s2
                        Log.v("card_names","-1");
                        Collections.swap(UserBoxGlbImageAdapter.mGLBIcons,s2Pos,s1Pos);
//                        UserBoxGlbImageAdapter.refreshFragmentView(UserBoxGLBFragment.getUserBoxAdapter());
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        return 100; // error code
                    }
                }
            });
```

Example: The List of Strings contains 3 elements in this order : "Terrifying Power","SSJ4","Androids". After the sorting process, their order is : "Androids","SSJ4","Terrifying Power".

Here is the starting order of the images:

[image]

and here is the right order:

[image]

And after the sorting process happens, the images just swap places and remain in the wrong order until i've run the sorting process like 20 times(i know i'm using the swap() method but i only want this to sort the images as needed so that they match up with the strings).

Comment: Your sorting of the icons is highly speculative. You could arrange names and icons in a list of pairs(you could use apache commons class Pair) and sort that list by the name.

Comment: can i do that since the images are part of an Adapter class which populates a GridView?

Comment: you could just replace the elements in the adapter class with the elements in the list of pairs in a simple loop. Or make something sophisticated with streams...

Comment: i am not sure if this would be helpful since along with the strings and images a bunch of other data are linked together

Comment: You can swap them, but you can't replace them in the right order?

Comment: replace them dynamically via code or change the code structure itself like you mentioned above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165379/discussion-between-turo-and-stelios-papamichael).